# Blur only one huge element's background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a page with a huge background which is fixed - as in:

```
body {
    background: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Now, to remove some focus from the background image, I thought about simply blurring it at the moment the real content starts. Think about a transparent jumbotron, followed by one giant div containing all the content. An example markup:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <nav>...</nav>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <div class="transparent-jumbotron">
        Big intro to the site goes here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        The actual content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

I have been trying out various hints and tricks on the internet - but the most I got was that `#page.contents` had the site's background - but upon scrolling a bit, it turned out that there was one instance of the background covering the original, and then there was the normal, unblurred background. This contents div also has a semi-transparent background applied through `rgba()` to darken the background.

So my question is: How can I blur the larger portion of a site, which has a fixed background image but much content that will require scrolling (as in, dynamicaly applying the blur filter)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use opacity property in css

```
opacity : <A number between 0 and 1, e.g:0.5 1 is fully focused and 0 makes the elmend hidden >;
```

Comment: Using the `opacity` property on the `#page.content` would affect its entire visibility...but i want to only modify the background, not also the visuals placed into that container.